# Send Outlook Email with Table in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I'm using the following code to generate and open an Outlook E-Mail. However I need to be able to insert a table with some variables and my current method only allows for basic text, could anyone suggest a way in which I could integrate a table?

```
  Try
       lblStatus.Text = "Opening OutLook Mail, Please Wait..."
        My.Application.DoEvents
        Dim Outl As Object
        Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        If Outl IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim omsg As Object
            omsg = Outl.CreateItem(0)
            omsg.body = "Table should go here"
            omsg.To = "*address goes here"
            omsg.subject = SubjectLine
            'set message properties here...'
            omsg.Display(false) 'will display message to user
            lblStatus.Text = "Outlook Mail Template Opened."
            My.Application.DoEvents
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblStatus.Text = "Opening OutLook Mail | Error Encountered"
           My.Application.DoEvents
        'log error
    End Try
```

Here's an example of what the table needs to be like:

[image]

Obviously there's formatting code used by Outlook, but I don't know how to send that from visual basic into the email.

Comment: `HTMLBody  = true`.  Then you could build the table very easily.

Comment: I don't want to use HTML as the receiver may not have it enabled and therefor will not display correctly all the time. My current way of thinking is to get vb to edit a .oft outlook template.

Answer (score 0):

First get the DoEvents() out of your code.  They are not helping anything.

As for the table, the simplest way to do it is to build the message body as a HTML string that includes the table.  Of course, that requires the receiver of the email set to accept HTML.

Comment: I don't want to use HTML as the receiver may not have it enabled and therefor will not display correctly all the time. My current way of thinking is to get vb to edit a .oft outlook template.

Comment: In this case, `DoEvents()` is being used as it should. It would be better (if the application's size/architecture justified it) to have a separate thread handling UI updates - however we don't know that the OP's application even uses multithreading (or should). In this case, it does the job. The rest of your answer is correct.

Comment: take a look at this...you might understand some of the issues with DoEvents();